# initializing an array using for loop with value of final array element as condition (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I would expect this code to print

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

but it only prints the first two elements of the array:

0 1

I realize I could just change the condition in my for loop to i < 10 to get the desired output, but I want to understand how/whether I can use the value of an element of the array to set the condition.

Thank you!

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int array[10];

    for(int i = 0; array[i] < 10; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is uninitialized, so the values it contains are **indeterminate**.  There' no guarantee that uninitialized values will contain any particular value, and in fact the value read may change on subsequent reads.

If you want meaningful results, the elements of the array need to be initialized with some value before you can read them.

Answer (score 4):

What you really want for your `for` loop is

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

The way you've got it now, you're checking the value of `array[i]` before it is given a value, meaning its value is whatever junk memory was on the stack when your function began.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the array element that you are looking is uninitialized, and contains garbage. You can check values that are initialised on the previous iteration, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int array[10];
    array[0]=0;
   printf("%d ", array[0]);
    for(int i = 1; array[i-1] < 9; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        printf("%d ", array[i]);

    }

}
```

I have made some changes to your code, please try this. If anyone has any suggestion or correction, please leave a comment.